# Ubuntu bluetooth slow to connect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

My Bluetooth headphones connect to my Android phone about 1-3 seconds after being switched on. Connecting the same headphones to my Ubuntu laptop (with Intel USB-2 Bluetooth driver) takes about a minute or sometimes longer.

Why so slow?

Can I do anything to improve this?

Answer (score 10):

I was able to fix it on Ubuntu 20.04.

You must add this config `FastConnectable=true` at `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`.

It comes `false` by default to power save. Hope it helps!

Comment: Worked for me on Manjaro, awesome. Just in case anyone doesn't know - you need to run `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` after saving the config file to apply it.